# Resources not loading after building the app to jar

Tags: java

My app works perfectly in the IDE, but when I build it to a jar the resources are not loaded at all. I tried using

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("path")
```

that didn't work as well.
my project structure looks like this:

[image]

I'm using Eclipse IDE,and I want to load the following:
1 - shared MP3 file (current.mp3)
2 - icon for swing (icon.jpg)
these 2 files located in resources folder.
i added resources as a source folder.

```
Image icon = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("resources/icon.jpg");
player = new Player(new FileInputStream("resources/current.mp3"));
OutputStream outstream = new FileOutputStream(new File("resources/current.mp3"));
```

Comment: What did you *actually* use as the resource path? How are you building the app to a jar?

Comment: I’m not using any building tools such as maven or gradle.